# how can access another schema table in same oracle apex application?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I have 2 schema, schemaA and schemaB. My application consist on schemaA 
and i can find all the tables of schemaA when create a form in oracle Apex
but in the same application i want to create a form of schemaB table

how will it possible please help ?

Comment: did you find a solution? I was able to add another schema to my workspace but I still can't figure how to query it

Comment: found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709164/select-data-from-another-schema-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick with database fundamentals. SchemaA needs SELECT access on schemaB.table_name.

I haven't tried with recent 19.x version, but APEX previously doesn't behave too well with synonyms in declarative forms, so you may need to define access via views.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the other schema added to your workspace. See your Workspace admin for this.
http://www.oraclenerd.com/2009/12/apex-assign-multiple-schemas-to-single.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e12512/adm_create_wkspc.htm#BABDEBHA

Answer (score 0):

To add another schema to your workspace you have to connect INTERNAL workspace (this workspace controls all other APEX workspaces in your Oracle container) and select menu "Manage Workspaces\Workspace Details". Then press the button "Schema Assigments" and then press the button "Add Schema" which runs "Add Schema" master. It guide you in four simple steps. In this manner you can add any numbers of schema to your workspace.