# Alternatives in sharing tables in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

say that i have an Oracle SQL Db (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise), and i have two schemas: schema1 and schema2 (same instance, clustered). I have a table that contains data that should be shared across these two schemas.

How many ways do i have to do this except for:

1. Granting privileges to a user from the other schema ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709164/select-data-from-another-schema-in-oracle))
2. Duplicate the table (i feel bad only thinking about this..synch problems ect)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's wrong with Option #1?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - nothing wrong exactly, it's just probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only other option is:

3. Building a view or a PL/SQL API over the table and granting privileges on that interface object

This would definitely be my preferred option. It is better than option **1** because it allows `schema1` (owner) to have more control over what `schema2` can see (e.g. filter rows, expose a subset of columns). It also allows `schema1` to change the table without `schema2` (necessarily) having to change their calling code. Much safer.

Note that if `schema2` is in a separate database then there are use cases for option **2**. I would be inclined to use a materialized view rather than a table, because that means Oracle does most of the work entailed by synchronisation. This means `schema2` can query the data even if the `schema1`'s database is down. (MViews can also be used even if the two schemas are in the same database, it's just the case is less compelling).

Option **2** is a bad choice if `schema2` needs to update, insert or delete the shared data. In that scenario always go for an interface.

If you do decide to apply option **1** and grant privileges on the table directly please have `schema2` create a synonym and reference that in its code. **Do not hardcode schema names in programs**.

Comment: I see, that actually sounds like the best way to break schema dependencies and bindings. Sill, we adopted another strategy: since the shared data was more related to one of the schemas than the other, we migrated that data to its closest schema and than set up a foreign key with the other schema in order to have coherence beetwen the two. Se basically we don't have a "grant select" but a "grant reference".
Anyway i will accept you answer as a solution since it explains clearly which other option is available, that was the original question

Answer (score 0):

If both schemas should be using the same data, then you should grant privileges to the second schema. If **schema1** owns the table and any changes to the table should also be seen by **schema2**, then yes it makes sense for both schemas to use the same table.